# What is the goal of glTexEnv?

Tags: opengl

Reading about point sprites for a particle system rendering, [in this site](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=770639&seqNum=7) they talk about point sprites and use the call `glTexEnvi(GL_POINT_SPRITE, GL_COORD_REPLACE, GL_TRUE);`

I tried to find info on this but everything points to the description given in the documentation of OpenGL, can someone give a more convenient example/explanation to understand the meaning of this?

Comment: there is a lot written on the [man page](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glTexEnv.xml)

Comment: By the way, what version of OpenGL are you using? I kind of assumed 2.0 here because in newer versions of GL you would generally use `gl_PointCoord` in a fragment shader instead of relying on this. This is sort of a throwback to fixed-function fragment processing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your title is a little broad, you are actually interested in one particular parameter (which is not explained in the manual page). However, if you read the formal specification for OpenGL 2.0, you will see that the parameter ***is*** explained there.

> #### [OpenGL Version 2.0 (October 22, 2004)](https://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec20.20041022.pdf)  -  *3.3. Points*  -  p. 100
>
> > ***All fragments*** produced in rasterizing a point sprite ***are assigned the same associated data***, which are those of the vertex corresponding to the point. **However,** for each texture coordinate set **where** **`GL_COORD_REPLACE`** is **`GL_TRUE`**, these texture coordinates are ***replaced with point sprite texture coordinates***.

Effectively what this means is that when disabled (default), the fragments produced during rasterization are assigned a single texture coordinate set. Those coordinates would be the ones associated with the single vertex that created the point sprite.

That behavior is not particularly useful though, because if every part of the point sprite has the same texture coordinates, then texture mapping is worthless. So as an alternative, GL can compute the texture coordinates itself and it does so by assigning the bottom-left corner (**0**,**0**) and the top-right corner of the sprite (**1**,**1**). This behavior is also customizable and if you are interested in reading more about how to assign which corner which coordinates, the linked part of the specification explains that in detail.

#### These [additional point parameters](http://what-when-how.com/opengl-programming-guide/point-sprites-opengl-programming/) are illustrated here:

[image: Origin diagram]